# Subsets of the space of continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I have a couple of questions regarding subsets of the space of continuous functions.

Let $U_1=\{f\in\mathcal{C}([a,b],\mathbb{R}):\min\{u(t):t\in[a,b]\}>1\}$. It is an open set of $\mathcal{C}([a,b],\mathbb{R})$. However, is $\partial U_1$ the set $\{f\in\mathcal{C}([a,b],\mathbb{R}):\min\{f(t):t\in[a,b]\}=1\}$?

Let $U_2=\{f\in\mathcal{C}([a,b],\mathbb{R}):\min\{u(t):t\in[a,b]\}>1, 1<\lVert f\rVert_0<2\}$, where $\lVert f\rVert_0=\max\{|f(t)|:t\in[a,b]\}$. It is an open set of $\mathcal{C}([a,b],\mathbb{R})$. Is $\partial U_2$ the union of $\{f\in\mathcal{C}([a,b],\mathbb{R}):\min\{f(t):t\in[a,b]\}=1,\lVert f\rVert_0=1\}$ and $\{f\in\mathcal{C}([a,b],\mathbb{R}):\min\{f(t):t\in[a,b]\}=1,\lVert f\rVert_0=2\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question: yes, $\partial U_1$ is indeed the set that you conjecture.
Hint: Calculate the closure of $U_1$, and then use $\partial U_1 = \overline{U_1}\setminus U_1$.

For your second question, that is not quite accurate. For instance, the constant function $2$ is in the closure of $U_2$, but not in the union.
For simplicity, is recommend rewriting $U_2$ as $\{ f \in C([a,b],\mathbb R) : 1< \min f([a,b]) \leq \max f([a,b]) < 2\}$ and then calculating the closure

Comment: So I would need to include the set ``minimum bigger than 1 and maximum equal 2''

Comment: yes, that sounds good

Comment: What do you think about the set $\{f \mid  \min f(t)>1, 2<\max f(t) <3\}$? Is it $\{\min=1,2\leq\max\leq3\}\cup\{\min>1,\max=2\}\cup\{\min>1,\max=3\}$?

Comment: i think that is right